# Override Spengo Filter in Websphere

Tags: security, websphere, websphere-7, jaas

Does anyone have any idea how I can override the Spengo web filter for websphere? I have a userId that has been validated from AD but this does not match the ID in out identity management software. So I need to get the ID out of the spengo/kerberos token call a web service to get the other ID and then override the AD ID with this one

Anyone have any pointers on how to do this? Am I considering the correct thing when I plan on overriding the spengo filter to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, would be to use login module. Check sample implementation on this page: [Mapping of a client Kerberos principal name to the WebSphere user registry ID](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-mp&topic=tsec_kerb_map)

Comment: That looks exactly like the thing I am looking for much appreciated. I will try it and let you know the result.